# Transform a positive integer into a string of multiple zeros

Tags: javascript

Here is an interesting question, in javascript what is the best way to convert a positive integer into a string of multiple zeros? For example `3` will be convertd to `'000'`, 7 will be converted to `'0000000'`.

I guess I can use a plain old for loop but it just seems to be too cumbersome to me.

Comment: `new Array(int+1).join("0")`

Comment: Not suggesting actually using this (hence not an answer), but this works.  `(Math.pow(10,3)+"").substring(1)`  Just the first thing I thought of, though I would never use it.

Comment: @Bergi Post as an answer? Seems like a great solution. edit: Ah, duplicate.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the notice, I didn't really realize that this can be generalized into a more common question.